# Multiple user login to iterate through a sequence of threads in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to simulate multiple user logging in and going through a sequence of web services in JMeter. The web services are-

1.login
2.startjob
3.endjob
4.logout

I have 10 users and all of them will simultaneously login and run through the steps 1-4.

The steps are-

1. User will login using "**login**" service. They will get a session token (ST) in the response.
2. Using the ST from above step the user will start the job using "**startjob**" service
3. After the job is finished, "**endjob**" service is used.
4. Finally user is logged out using "**logout**" service.

So far I have been able to do the above steps properly for one user.

I have created a CSV file with 10 usernames and passwords and am able to make only the "login" service iterate through all users using CSV Data Set Config.

**How do I make each individual user go through steps 1-4?**

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter, each individual **`Thread or User`** will execute every sample within it in  **upside-down** order. So for a single user, when we run the test, the result will appear in that order. But `Ramp up` time is related to Thread creation:

> How long JMeter should take to get all the threads started is the
>   **`Ramp up`** time.

Within this time, all the users will be initiated and all those Threads will execute the samples underlying it in the same fashion as it does for a single user.So in you case, all the 10 thread will go through steps 1-4, but  the threads will initiate within  your ramp up time.

If you observe the output in **`View Results in Table`** listener and trace the `Start Time` of the samples for a corresponding  Thread, you will see that those samples are executed through  **the steps of 1-4**.

For an example, I have **`4 samples`** under my `Thread Group` and I have defined  **`Threads or Users : 3`** and **`Ramp up : 5`**. All those three Threads executed the samples Through 1 to 4.

**Image here:**

[image]

Comment: I was able to do as u said and run  the thread runs for all 10 users, but instead of taking the individual ST for each user it takes the last ST from the last user and applies it to all the consecutive threads. Do you know how I can do that?